# CAOpenGLLayer to image

Tags: cocoa, opengl, calayer, nsview, nsimage

Is there any way to capture the contents of a `CAOpenGLLayer` as an image?

The `CALayer` route using `renderInContext:` doesn't work (empty image) in 10.14 and as per Apple's comments:

> The OS X v10.5 implementation of this method does not support the
>   entire Core Animation composition model. QCCompositionLayer,
>   CAOpenGLLayer, and QTMovieLayer layers are not rendered.

Apparently this was never fixed.

The `NSView` route using

```
NSBitmapImageRep* rep = [self bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:self.bounds];
[self cacheDisplayInRect:self.bounds toBitmapImageRep:rep];
```

doesn't work either resulting in an equally empty image..

When invoked on the view containing the `CAOpenGLLayer` it results in an entirely empty image, on the view's window's `contentView` the window content is there -
except for the area covered by the OpenGL view, which is neatly 'cut out' (blank)..

Any suggestions on how to render OpenGL content to an `NSImage` much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to capture the contents of the layer, you need to get the layer's drawing code to render into a buffer explicitly and give that buffer back to you.